# Teradata SQL: Dynamically generate VARCHAR rows in a single column

Tags: sql, teradata

I have this script that generates dates in a column at 3 month intervals:

```
select
    extract(year from end(pd)) * 100 + extract(month from end(pd)) as ym     
    ,last_day(end(pd)) as mth

    from sys_calendar.calendar               

    where calendar_date = date '2015-02-28'  
    expand on period(add_months(calendar_date,-3), add_months(calendar_date,12))
      as pd by interval '3' month
```

Output is:

```
ym      mth
201502  2015-02-28
201505  2015-05-31
201508  2015-08-31
201511  2015-11-30
201602  2016-02-29
```

I want to add a column that will look like this:

```
    ym      mth         label
    201502  2015-02-28  Interval_0
    201505  2015-05-31  Interval_1
    201508  2015-08-31  Interval_2
    201511  2015-11-30  Interval_3
    201602  2016-02-29  Interval_4
```

Is there a way to dynamically generate that last column?  A modified version of this script will be part of a query that will pull the month_end_date for an account in a partitioned table and then generate dates in 3 month intervals off of that month_end_date, going out 1 year.

The output needs to go into a spreadsheet for further analysis and that 'label' column will allow me to flag a date as belonging to a certain interval.

Comment: You could do some kind of horrible thing with concatenating interval and the output from row_number.

Comment: @Andrew: I would consider this being *reasonable* instead of *horrible*  :-)

Comment: I guess I just think `'interval_' || cast(row_number( ...) -1 as varchar(2))` is pretty ugly... But it should work.